# Python doesn't seem to find installed module anymore

Tags: python-2.7, error-handling, module, scipy, package

I apologies for the trivial question but when I tried to run a few scripts this morning that had been working for months I came across the following error message:

```
import scipy.stats
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-b66176eb2d0a>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.stats

ImportError: No module named stats
```

So I get the problem that Python doesn't seem to find the stats package in the scipy folder, yet I double checked that I indeed had a scipy folder in the Python install directory as well as a stats folder within the scipy folder.

I do have the following: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\`

I use Spyder, I tried reloading the kernel, closing and reopening Spyder but nothing seems to work.

Further info;

I do have an `__init__.py` in the scipy folder.

The `import scipy` command works

attempts to load other packages within scipy also throw the error

Any help would be very welcome if you encountered the same problem before !

EDIT:

Okay so I restarted the kernel from the python console once more and did the following, which works:

```
import os

os.getcwd()
Out[2]: 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages'

from scipy import stats
```

The bug has now moved on to another package...

I suspect that when I am running my script which is located on another drive Python struggles to find the packages. My puzzles me is that it didn't use to.

Comment: can you  `print(sys.executable)` ?

Comment: Yes, I get : `C:\Python27\python.exe`

Comment: is there a `__init__.py` in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy` ?

Comment: Yes and a config as well. For info I can import `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\random` without any problem

Comment: Also none of the files in the scipy folder have been modified recently according to the Windows `Date modified` sorting